# Illuminate components in packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a self-made package. With the service provider I pass the `$app` instance to the actual class. Then I use:

```
$this->app['session']->get('key', 'value');
```

to use the Session component's functionality. However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Using $this when not in object context

So I tried just using

```
Session::get( ... )
```

but then it says it doesn't find the class.

How do I solve this?

This is my full class:

```
namespace AlexCogn\Messenger;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as Application;

    class Messenger
    {
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public static function messages()
    {
         $messages = $this->app['session']->get('messages', array());

         $this->app['session']->forget('messages');

         return $messages;
    }

    public function addMessage($message)
    {
         $messages = $this->app['session']->get('messages', array());
         array_push($messages, $message);

         $this->app['session']->put('messages', $messages);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

apparently not everyone understands the question: I am calling Messenger through a Facade:

```
Messenger::addMessage('test');
```

and I thought Laravel converted this to 
    $app['messenger']->addMessage('test');

So shouldn't this be called via an instance?

Comment: It should, but your problem is that you're defining your method as static. Now when ```$app['messenger']->addMessage('test');``` is called it a call from an instance, not static call anymore.

Comment: @crynobone thanks, removing static from the method declarations solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `$this` from a static method within your class. This won't work. By PHP definition (and also because it'd be stupid otherwise), `$this` is only available in the following scopes:

- Inside a method that has been called through an instance (i.e. `$this->foo()`)
- Inside a class constructor (inside `__construct()`)
- Inside a `Callable` where this has been redefined using the Runkit library

Anything else causes `this` to trigger the fatal error you have just received. I cannot suggest a fix, as you did not put your code up - however, if you do, I'll be more than happy to find a solution for you.

Comment: I know that, but isn't this something Laravel specific? The rest of the code shouldn't be that important? I'll edit the question

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau: hint: the first five characters of the line of code you pasted is `$this`. Post the entire body of the method - and I bet you that you'll come across the `static` keyword while doing so.

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau: Now, you need to call the method dynamically wherever you call it. Just removing the `static` keyword isn't going to fix anything - not having it means your method can be static or dynamic (but PHP will throw a warning if you try to call a method statically).